# How to create an Ionic v6 Project based on Angular

Tags: ionic-framework

In versions of the Ionic framework, after Ionic v2, an Ionic v3 Angular project can be created by setting --type=ionic-angular e.g.

```
ionic start MyApp blank --type=ionic-angular
```

So even if Ionic v5 is installed the above command would create an Ionic v3 Angular project.

My question is how can I always create an Ionic v6 Angular project, even if I install the latest version of Ionic in 6 months time? E.g. When Ionic v7 is released will there be a way to create an Ionic v6 Angular project?

Comment: Why would you want to? Starting new projects on old versions seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It will not change, it will stay the same as you posted.

Comment: If you mean the way to create an Ionic v3 project (by saying --type=ionic-angular) in a new version of Ionic, then that's OK. 
But in Ionic v6 the way to create an Ionic v6 project is by saying --type=angular. If I install Ionic v7, saying --type=ionic-angular will still create a v3 project; but will --type=angular still create a v6 project, or will it create v7 project?

Comment: you dont have to even use --type. it will ask you which framework you want and all you got to do is select. It will Not create a v7 project until ionic has a public release.

Answer (score -1):

You can force it by installing @ionic/angular version to current version in your package.json file.

However, Ionic is a very unstable framework even after 10 years. Every time there is a new release, old plugins completely get messed up. And you need to update plugins to stay in sync with iOS/Android updates. I have wasted so many hours every time there is a new Ionic or Capacitor release. The process is never straightforward.